# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Paint.getAlpha()' on a null object reference

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Имеется некое приложение, на одних устройствах оно норм работает, на других оно крашится, при попытке открыть новую активити. 
Вот лог ошибки

```
Process: xxxxxxxxxxxxx, PID: 26405
                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Paint.getAlpha()' on a null object reference
                                                                             at android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable.draw(NinePatchDrawable.java:250)
                                                                             at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.draw(LayerDrawable.java:517)
                                                                             at android.widget.ProgressBar.drawTrack(ProgressBar.java:1692)
                                                                             at android.widget.ProgressBar.onDraw(ProgressBar.java:1659)
                                                                             at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15606)
                                                                             at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14495)
                                                                             at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14524)
                                                                             at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15315)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3536)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3329)
                                                                             at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14487)
                                                                             at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14524)
                                                                             at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15315)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3536)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3329)
                                                                             at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14487)
                                                                             at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14524)
                                                                             at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15315)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3536)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3329)
                                                                             at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15618)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:658)
                                                                             at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14495)
                                                                             at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14524)
                                                                             at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15315)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3536)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3329)
                                                                             at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14487)
                                                                             at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14524)
                                                                             at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15315)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3536)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3329)
                                                                             at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15618)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:658)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.draw(NestedScrollView.java:1768)
                                                                             at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14495)
                                                                             at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14524)
                                                                             at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15315)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3536)
                                                                             at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.drawChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1230)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3329)
                                                                             at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14487)
                                                                             at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14524)
                                                                             at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15315)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3536)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3329)
                                                                             at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14487)
                                                                             at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14524)
                                                                             at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15315)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3536)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3329)
                                                                             at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14487)
                                                                             at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14524)
                                                                             at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15315)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3536)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3329)
                                                                             at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14487)
                                                                             at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14524)
                                                                             at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15315)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3536)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3329)
                                                                             at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14487)
                                                                             at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14524)
                                                                             at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15315)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3536)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3329)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchDraw
```

в `xml` есть `ProgressBar`, `RoundedImageView`, и `TextView`.
Прошу вашей помощи.

Comment: по коду ошибки идет попытка обратиться к методу объекта ссылка на который null - `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Paint.getAlpha()' on a null object reference`
может там где крашится какие-то нюансы по использованию объекта Paint?

Comment: дело в том что я на нескольких девайсах прогнал, и воспроизвести ошибку не удалось,а у тестеров эта ошибка на всех девайсах, что меня очень удивило. Может кто сталкивался с этой ошибкой... Есть подозрение что ошибка вылетает из за progressBar

Comment: это конкретная ошибка, сам на нее нарываюсь пару раз  неделю - вы передаете куда-то ссылку на объект и там идет использование методов этого объекта, а у вас в каком-то случае (который словили тестеры) передается null, ну или теряется (что маловероятно). И еще в логе должна быть строка где ошибка вылетает, за это можно уцепиться.